# SQL Query (maybe simple)

Tags: sql, oracle

So i'm having this problem.

I have two tables (Oracle), one is called Destination and the other one Reserve. Reserve has a foreign key to the id of Destination (Because on reserve has one destination). And reserve tuples means all the reserves that all the users have done. I need a way to check the top 3 most visited Destinations (based on the foreign key in the table Reserve).

How can I do that with SQL in Oracle. I know that I need to search within the Reserve tables for the 3 most repeated Destinations ID's, and later join that with the Destination table to get the details of the top 3 destinations.

Any help is valid. Thank you very much.

SCHEMA:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
--  File created - martes-septiembre-15-2009   
--------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Table DESTINO
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE "S2501A29"."DESTINO" 
   (    "PK_ID_DESTINO" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "FK_COD_UBICACION_GEOGRAFICA" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "NOMBRE" VARCHAR2(10), 
    "FOTO" VARCHAR2(30), 
    "DESCRIPCION" VARCHAR2(50)
   ) ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Table LUGAR_ESTADIA
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE "S2501A29"."LUGAR_ESTADIA" 
   (    "PK_ID_ESTADIA" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "NOMBRE" VARCHAR2(10), 
    "TIPO" VARCHAR2(10), 
    "DESCRIPCION" VARCHAR2(50), 
    "COSTO_SERVICIOS" NUMBER, 
    "DESCRIPCION_ALOJAMIENTO" VARCHAR2(100), 
    "DESCRIPCION_ALIMENTACION" VARCHAR2(100)
   ) ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Table OPCION_TRANSPORTE
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE "S2501A29"."OPCION_TRANSPORTE" 
   (    "PK_ID_VIAJE" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "MEDIO_TRANSPORTE" VARCHAR2(10), 
    "RESPONSABLE" VARCHAR2(10), 
    "CIUDAD_ORIGEN" VARCHAR2(10), 
    "CIUDAD_DESTINO" VARCHAR2(10), 
    "COSTO" NUMBER
   ) ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Table RESERVA
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE "S2501A29"."RESERVA" 
   (    "PK_ID_RESERVA" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "FK_COD_DESTINO" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "FK_COD_ESTADIA" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "FK_COD_VIAJE" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "TARJETA_CREDITO" VARCHAR2(12), 
    "FECHA_SALIDA" DATE, 
    "FECHA_REGRESO" DATE, 
    "NOMBRE_USUARIO" VARCHAR2(50)
   ) ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Table UBICACION_GEOGRAFICA
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE "S2501A29"."UBICACION_GEOGRAFICA" 
   (    "PK_ID_UBICACION" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "CIUDAD" VARCHAR2(10), 
    "PAIS" VARCHAR2(10), 
    "CONTINENTE" VARCHAR2(10)
   ) ;
```

Just a note:

RESERVE is Reserva
DESTINATION is Destino

Because the DB is in spanish. Thanks!

Comment: This would be easier if you gave us an exact schema of the DB. Like the CREATE TABLE statements that would duplicate your setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but what about grouping by foreign key and sorting by the resulting values?

**Edit:** Something like:

```
select FK_COD_DESTINO, count(*) as qty from RESERVA group by FK_COD_DESTINO order by qty desc limit 3
```

Comment: Hey budy thanks!

That works perfect except for one thing... if I put the limit, it doesn't work for oracle, just for mysql

the query working is:

select fk_cod_destino, count(*) as cantidad from RESERVA group by fk_cod_destino order by cantidad desc

Comment: Does LIMIT exist in Oracle?  I thought it was only available for MySQL.

Comment: How can I limit the result to 3 by using the oracle WHERE rownum <= 3
I putted it at the end but doesn't work. Sorry for so many questions and for my bad english.

Comment: Sorry, I have used "limit" before on MySQL and PostgreSQL, I assumed Oracle had it too :/

Comment: You can o the same in oracle by querying the sorted set with a "rownum < 4" condition:
select * from (select FK_COD_DESTINO, count(*) as qty from RESERVA group by FK_COD_DESTINO order by qty desc) where rownum < 4;

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
WITH CountsByDestination
AS
(
  SELECT FK_COD_DESTINO, 
         COUNT(*) CNT
  FROM Reservations
  GROUP BY DestinationId
),
RankingByDestination
AS
(
  SELECT FK_COD_DESTINO,
         CNT,
         RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CNT) RNK
  FROM CountsByDestination
)
SELECT *
FROM RankingByDestination R
INNER JOIN Destinations D ON D.PK_ID_DESTINO = R.FK_COD_DESTINO
WHERE R.RNK BETWEEN 1 AND 3
ORDER BY R.RNK
```

This retains ties, so if two or more destinations share the same counts they should appear as part of the result set.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle doesn't support `limit`.  This should work for you.

```
select A.FK_COD_DESTINO
     , A.COUNT
     , A.RANK
     , B.*
  from (select FK_COD_DESTINO
             , count(*) as COUNT
             , rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as RANK
          from RESERVA
         group by FK_COD_DESTINO) A
  join DESTINO B on B.PK_ID_DESTINO = A.FK_COD_DESTINO
 where A.RANK <= 3
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try HAVING rownum <=3